# objective-c pointer to 'int *' error when assigning data across relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c

In this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started, the author creates two classes FailedBankInfo and FailedBankDetails from two core data entities, which have a relationship between them, and when he assigns the object failedBankDetails to the name of the relationship `details` on the failedBankInfo object/pointer like this

```
failedBankInfo.details = failedBankDetails;
```

it generates this error

```
implicit conversion of an objective-c pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with arc
```

and the same error is generated when he assigns info.details to the pointer `FailedBankDetails *  details`

```
for (FailedBankInfo *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.name);
    FailedBankDetails *details = info.details;
    NSLog(@"Zip: %@", details.zip);
}
```

Can you explain why this is happening?

This is the full code that he instructs reader to insert into applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    FailedBankInfo *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankInfo"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    failedBankInfo.name = @"Test Bank";
    failedBankInfo.city = @"Testville";
    failedBankInfo.state = @"Testland";
    FailedBankDetails *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankDetails"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];
        failedBankDetails.closeDate = [NSDate date];
        failedBankDetails.updateDate = [NSDate date];
        failedBankDetails.zip = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];
        failedBankDetails.info = failedBankInfo;
        failedBankInfo.details = failedBankDetails;
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        // Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (FailedBankInfo *info in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.name);
            FailedBankDetails *details = info.details;
            NSLog(@"Zip: %@", details.zip);
        }
```

Before generating classes for the entities, he performed the same task/test just using the managedObject and there was no problem

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankInfo"
    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Test Bank" forKey:@"name"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Testville" forKey:@"city"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Testland" forKey:@"state"];
NSManagedObject *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankDetails"
    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"closeDate"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"updateDate"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12345] forKey:@"zip"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:failedBankInfo forKey:@"info"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:failedBankDetails forKey:@"details"];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"name"]);
    NSManagedObject *details = [info valueForKey:@"details"];
    NSLog(@"Zip: %@", [details valueForKey:@"zip"]);
}
```

Comment: Please share FailedBankDetails.h with us.

Comment: ... and FailedBankInfo.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks as if the "details" property of "FailedBackInfo" is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) int *details;
```

and not – as it should be – as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FailedBankDetails *details;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial it says you can change the type of the info/detail variable in the h file depending on which one you create first manually. I found that this didn't work. I think your problem may be solved by deleting the subclass that you created first and then recreating it. That way it should link up with the entity relationships to info/detail (whichever you did second) properly